# How did this game end in a draw?

Tags: endgame, draw, claim-draw, threefold-repetition

https://en.lichess.org/B6L5XNox

Never mind the sloppy play. I'm just curious why this ended in a draw:

(Does anyone know how to copy moves from lichess?)

Anyway, the final 5 moves:

58. Rc4+ Kb6
59. Qd8+ Kb5
60. Qd5+ Kb6
61. Rb4+ Kc7
62. Rc4+ Kb6

There was no 3-fold repetition and the King still has places to move.

Answer (score 6):

There was a three-times repetition. Note that only the position needs to be repeated, it is not necessary that the moves leading to the position are the same. The position occurred first after move 58, second after move 60 and third at the end of the game.

Comment: Really? I thought both moves would have to be replicated. What's to stop a person (lower ranked for instance) from doing that with his knight in the first 5 moves for instance?

Comment: @StackOverflowed: Well, there are two players in the game. When one player plays passively, the other is not obliged to do the same. So when White move a knight to and fro, Black just develops her pawns and pieces and plays for a win.

Comment: @StackOverflowed: the _entire position_ needs to be repeated, but the moves in between don't matter.

Answer (score 0):

If a position is repeated three times, not necessarily consecutively, with the same party to move, that's one definition of a draw, which was true in this case.